# Make HTML/Javascript Geolocation function more linear

Tags: javascript, html, html5, callback

I'm checking users locations with HTML Geolocation before unlocking the front door.  Geolocation takes a few seconds in addition to the time it takes the user to approve it, so currently I have a callback for what to do next.

```
function getLocationWithCallbacks(callback, error_callback) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function (position) {
        let location = { "latitude": position.coords.latitude, "longitude": position.coords.longitude };
        callback(location);
      },
      function (error) {
        if (error.code === error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
          error_callback()
      }
  )
}
```

And I call this function like so..

```
getLocationWithCallbacks(unlock_request, get_location_denied);
```

However, I'm not sure if there's a more logical way than this.  It would be nice if events happened in a more linear fashion like ("pseudo code")...

```
function getLocation() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   function(position) { return ['success', position] },
   function(error) { return ['failure', error] }
}
```

And invoke it with...

```
let response = getLocation();
response[0] === 'success' ? unlock_request(response[1]) : get_location_denied(response[1])
```

However I believe this would involve adding promises and await statements which might make the original callback method more desirable.

I'm just not sure what's the cleanest, most logical way of implementing a getLocation function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most native functions require callback instead of `Promise` because they support older browsers, so what you have to do is to pack the `method` in a `Promise`

```
function getLocation() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) { resolve(position); },
            function(error) { reject(error); }
        }
    });
}
```

Now are able to determine what should happen with the `position` and the `error`.

```
const response = getLocation()
    .then(position => 
        ( {"latitude": position.coords.latitude, 
           "longitude": position.coords.longitude} ))
    .then(latLong => { unlock_request(latLong) }, 
          error => { get_location_denied(error[1]) });
```

You know that for this `request` that you want to get the `latitude` and `longitude` out of `position` so you just return a new `object` with `longitude` and `latitude`, the smart thing with promises is that is it a builder pattern, so can call `then` again and now the parameter will be what was returned in the last `then`, so all power is given to `response` rather than `getLocation()`